# how to Display an error message in case of app crash (or just freezes)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am building an in-house application. My manager told that my app freezes time to time and she has to restrat the whole iPad to restrat the app. How can I handle these kind of sudden app crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I handle these kind of sudden app crashes?

Debug your application using Instruments, that will help you locate why the app freeze.

Besides, if it crashes, you can plug the phone on your Mac and retrieve the Crash Log, then analyze in which method it has crashed. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html).